# how to change the font size of h2 tag in the html

Tags: html, css, mongodb, meteor

I am using meteor and mongo there is a template I am using the h2 tag to display the header. But I want to change the font size of this h2 tag. I tried in CSS but it is not taking. if I refresh the page it will take the previous values. So can anyone suggest me how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this 
1. Using inline css
 just do

```
<h2 style="font-size:40px !important;"></h2>
```

2. Using Internal css

```
<style>
h2{
 font-size:40px !important;
}
</style>
```

3. Using External css

just assign a class to your h2 element and add size to that class on external css

```
<h2 class="headding"></h2>
```

and then

```
.headding{
   font-size:40px !important;
}
```

you can use size like **40px,40%,40vw,**etc.

Answer (score 2):

First define your **CSS** of with h2 tag at end of header's file and add code like that

> **`!important;`** is override all previous values 
>   you must have to write **!important** at end of line to override previous value

```
<style>
h2 {
    font-size: 20px !important;
}
</style>
```

Comment: As I am fresher to this field so I am facing some problems. It is working now thanks for spending your valuable time.

Answer (score 0):

Using large is a bad practice that should be avoided as much as possible. Instead, work on the accuracy of the selector used, like this little example :

```
<div class="my_container">
    <div class="other_class">
        <h2>
     </div>
</div>

And...
.my_container {
   .other_class {
      h2 {
        // your override 
      }
   }
}
```

So you have to be more precise than the old selector to get your hands on it.